# Best Approach for Assignment Code in Node.js (ES6 style)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to improve this code? Using ES6 style i am using latest stable version of node.js.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
date: string;
dateObj: {
    year: number,
    month: number,
    day: number
};
project: string;
task: string;
hours: number;
});

let data = new Data();
data.date = new Date(body.date);
    data.dateObj = {
        year: body.dateObj.year,
        month: body.dateObj.month,
        day: body.dateObj.day
    }
    data.project = body.project;
    data.task = body.task;
    data.hours = body.hours;
}
```

Comment: We first need to know what your code is accomplishing. Please [edit] your question and describe the assignment ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For flat objects (i.e. whose values are only primitive types), there's `Object.assign()`, which shallow-copies all [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) keys and values from one object to the other:

```
Object.assign(data, body);
```

However, in your case, shallow-copying means the `dateObj` member of the `body` would get copied by reference, instead of creating a new object and recursively copying its keys and values.

You can also try using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) `...`, which was introduced recently:

```
let data = new Data();

Object.assign(data, {
    // Shallow-copy all keys and values from body:
    ...body,

    // Overwrite certain keys:
    date: new Date(body.date),
    dateObj: { ...body.dateObj },
});
```

Whether or not this code is readable or intuitive is up to you to decide.

Also, as a minor note, `Object.assign` returns the first object you pass to it, so instead of this:

```
let data = new Data();
Object.assign(data, { /* ...properties */ });
```

You can write this:

```
let data = Object.assign(new Data(), { /* ...properties */ });
```